# Uncaught ReferenceError: function not defined and it mark <DOCTYPE HTML>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to submit form through ajax but function not defined and i browser inspect element mark `<DOCOTYPE HTML>` please find code below

```
<form method="post" id="search_form" action="" name="search">
    <div>
        <select name="car_id" id="car_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name="km_id" id="km_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" align="center" style="font-size: 20px;padding-top: 50px;padding-bottom: 150px;">
        <input class="btn-danger" id="search_button" name="search" onclick="search_function('locations.php')" type="button" value="search" />
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function search_function($responce) {
    $("#syana").innerHTML = '<img align="center" style="width:100px;height: 100px;margin-right: 300px;" src="loading.gif" />';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $responce,
        data: $("form").serialize(),

        success: function(data) {
            $("#search").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fix the PHP!")
        }
    });
```

note that same function used in another page and run successsfully

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
```

The corect one is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: yes i mean<!DOCTYPE html> but am confuse because code didn't run so write it wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The function should be initialized before the input button. So please use this code instead:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function search_function($responce) {
    $("#syana").innerHTML = '<img align="center" style="width:100px;height: 100px;margin-right: 300px;" src="loading.gif" />';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $responce,
        data: $("form").serialize(),

        success: function(data) {
            $("#search").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fix the PHP!")
        }
    });
};
</script>
<form method="post" id="search_form" action="" name="search">
    <div>
        <select name="car_id" id="car_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name="km_id" id="km_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" align="center" style="font-size: 20px;padding-top: 50px;padding-bottom: 150px;">
        <input class="btn-danger" id="search_button" name="search" onclick="search_function('locations.php')" type="button" value="search" />
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
```

Comment: It is working here, is the javascript error the same or it is different?

Comment: when change place of function and put in another file it give me this message in console             Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Leave it in the same file just change the order. Please try with the code I have provided you because i fixed some errors in your code and write us what has happened.

Comment: when i leave it in same file and change order nothing happen and get same error